# How to configure Hibernate Envers to avoid certain collections (join tables) in entity revision queries

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, audit, hibernate-envers

I am using Hibernate `Envers 4.2`, I want to fetch the revisions of entity with only details from some of the collections in the Entity.

But I could see hibernate queries fired for all collections in the Entity causing performance problems.

Also could not use `@NotAudited` annotation for the collections to avoid in this particular query as the auditing is desired in other scenarios for those collections.

For example, if my Audited Entity has these two joins as collections.
But I want the query getting revisions of my entity to fetch only address information and ignore Order information, is it possible? I don't want to annotate Order information with @NotAudited since the history information may be desired in other scenarios.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ADDR_ID")
public Address getAddress() { return address; }

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="CUST_ID") 
public Set<Order> getOrders() {return orders;}
```

Comment: Could you use a projection-based query instead to solve your problem?

Comment: I need to fetch the details of some of join tables. I am not able to do projection on join tables in Auditquery. I am getting the error as 'property not resolved' though the join table is audited

Comment: Could you show your entities and code so we have an idea of what you're trying exactly here?

Comment: Are you certain you don't have code calling the `#getOrders()` method that is causing the collection to be hydrated?  AFAIK, that collection should be lazily initialized when the getter method is called.

Comment: Yes. I am using Auditreader.find method(https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/envers/AuditReader.html#find(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Number))  to get the details of a version of the entity.But could verify that hibernate queries are formed for all collections in the entity. But If I annotate certain collections of an entity with @NotAudited, hibernate queries are not formed for those collections.

Comment: Anything that is explicitly marked as `@NotAudited` will effectively be null when you query for an audited historical record because you've explicitly specified that tracking of that attribute was not required.  It's important to remember that an audit query does not return a "real" entity like ORM does but simply returns an instance of your entity class populated with the respective audited attributes only; nothing more.  If a collection is marked to be audited, then a query generator will be constructed for that association, but the results of that collection are not always eagerly loaded.

Comment: Thanks. Anyways I observe that making the collection as '@NotAudited' significantly speeds up the Audit query for revision.Would like to know if its possible to achieve the same speedup without making collection '@NotAudited'

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As in [this Hibernate documentation example](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/886e1bcc300c3cc617e46d39b1831d127bc6c9d1/documentation/src/test/java/org/hibernate/userguide/envers/QueryAuditWithModifiedFlagTest.java#L148), If I have a `Customer` with an `Address` association:

```
@Audited( withModifiedFlag = true )
@Entity(name = "Customer")
public class Customer {

    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Address address;

}
```

and I query the revisions using [this query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#envers-tracking-properties-changes-queries-hasChanged-example):

```
List<Customer> customers = AuditReaderFactory
.get( entityManager )
.createQuery()
.forRevisionsOfEntity( Customer.class, false, true )
.add( AuditEntity.id().eq( 1L ) )
.add( AuditEntity.property( "lastName" ).hasChanged() )
.getResultList();
```

Envers only queries for `Customers`, not `Address`:

```
select
    c.id as id1_3_0_,
    c.REV as REV2_3_0_,
    defaultrev1_.REV as REV1_4_1_,
    c.REVTYPE as REVTYPE3_3_0_,
    c.REVEND as REVEND4_3_0_,
    c.created_on as created_5_3_0_,
    c.createdOn_MOD as createdO6_3_0_,
    c.firstName as firstNam7_3_0_,
    c.firstName_MOD as firstNam8_3_0_,
    c.lastName as lastName9_3_0_,
    c.lastName_MOD as lastNam10_3_0_,
    c.address_id as address11_3_0_,
    c.address_MOD as address12_3_0_,
    defaultrev1_.REVTSTMP as REVTSTMP2_4_1_
from
    Customer_AUD c cross
join
    REVINFO defaultrev1_
where
    c.id = ?
    and c.lastName_MOD = ?
    and c.REV=defaultrev1_.REV
order by
    c.REV asc

-- binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT]  - [1]
-- binding parameter [2] as [BOOLEAN] - [true]
```

Unless you navigate associations like this:

```
AuditQuery innerJoinAuditQuery = AuditReaderFactory
.get( entityManager )
.createQuery()
.forEntitiesAtRevision( Customer.class, 1 )
.traverseRelation( "address", JoinType.INNER );
```

Hibernate Envers should not include them in the SQL revision query.

Comment: I am not using traverseRelation. I am using method  AuditReader.find(entity, uuid, revisonNum) . I see separate 'select query' fired for all the collections in the entity. The collections are annotated as below. I tried lazy fetch too but observe select query fired for all collections which result in slowness of the revision query.
    `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`
`@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)`

Comment: I tried Lazy fetch too but still observe select query fired for all collections in the Entity when querying for revision.

Comment: You can use a native query as dell. The Invers table are just table after all.

Comment: I observed Envers tables holds only modified data for each version,but I need complete information for each version. There are many joins which needs to be navigated and converted back to Java objects for each version and using native query is not feasible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155109/discussion-between-sivaramtechfan-and-vlad-mihalcea).

Comment: I had to vote this answer down, because I have the same problem and the given solution doesn't work. @sivaramtechfan, was there another solution that worked for you?